# Dell Latitude E5450 runs (Minecraft) better on battery

Tags: laptop, performance, power-supply, battery, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 (Windows 11, Intel Core i5-5300U, Nvidia GeForce 830M, 16GB) and have noticed that in sometimes it runs better on battery than plugged in, specificly playing Minecraft (game).

But it isn't very consistent, sometimes Minecraft runs well pluged in, and Blender (3D software) tested just after playing Minecraft and having problems, runs better pluged in.

Since the first time this happend I have clean instaled Windows, and it continues after restarting.

There are <s>three</s> two things I think could be causing this:

<s>Minecraft/Java itself.</s> see update

Different performance settings for battery and plugged in, where the ones for plugged in are too high. But I heven't found something like this anywhere yet.

The [User Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/latitude-e5450-laptop/dell_latitude_e5450_om-v1/technical-specifications?guid=guid-ff58d80e-59c8-4c89-bcf1-57aedc89cc0d&lang=en-us) mentions a 90W version of the AC addapter (mine is 65W) could it be that mine can't suply enough power? And on battery it works because the battery can? Is there any way for me to confirm this?

What do you think? Is it any of these things?

**Update:** This seems to be a general gaming problem because Minecraft for Windows (Writen in C++ and not Java) has the same problems.

**Update 2:** I tried using the integrated GPU and didn't have problems, so the problem is probably from the dedicated GPU.

Comment: Is this a model with discrete video card (NVidia)? And if so, did you check which video card Minecraft is using when performance is subpar?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I have a Nvidia GeForce 830M, and that is what Minecraft is using, will update the question.

Comment: What are your settings for *Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings*, under "Processor power management", settings for Minimum & Maximum.

Comment: @harrymc They're 5 and 100% for both (On battery and Plugged in).

Comment: You should perhaps investigate which GPU is used by which program when plugged-in or not.

Comment: When I play I close all other apps, and for Minecraft I use my dedicated GPU.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs better" - FPS ?

Comment: Alot better, 6 vs 54FPS. Sodium (performance mod) gets it to 13 vs 60FPS. These with ten chunks, fast graphics, but it doesn't get much better with only two chunks.

Comment: Just to rule it out, the charger you are using, is it the original charger to the device or a third-party replacement?

Comment: It is original.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue!

I went into the BIOS just to check if there was anything there, while checking I turned on "POST Behavior > Adaptor warnings". When I restarted I got a warning that the power addapter wattage could not be determined and system performance would be tuned down (found somewhere that clock speed is halved).

I tried many thing I found online but none worked.

Since then I have got a new charger and the problem has not happened since (2 months).